# How to add an arbitrary ProblemMarker in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

Without relying on any external validation, I want to simply invoke an IAction (say from a right click menu option on a file) and create a ProblemMarker. I would just have my own validation logic, inside the IAction, which validates the file input and adds this ProblemMarker at a given location with a given custom message. It would also be able to delete all markers too. I assume if you can add a marker that you can also delete one too.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new marker you need the Resource and the Position of the marker. Here is an example how to create the marker.  `res.createMarker("markerId");` creates the marker with a given id. You can create custom Markers using extension point or use the from eclipse defined. You can find the defined Markers in `org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker`

```
protected static void createBasicMarker(final IResource res, Position pos) throws CoreException {
    final IMarker marker = res.createMarker("markerId");
    annotation.setMarker(marker);
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, position.getOffset());
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, position.getOffset() + position.getLength());
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, 1);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, IMarker.PRIORITY_LOW);
    setMarkerMessage(annotation, marker);
}
```